# Installing Passenger installs Apache as well?

Tags: apache2, passenger

I have a new machine installed with Ubuntu 11.04 + RVM + Ruby 1.9.2 so far.  I now want to install Apache + Passenger.

I'm trying to work out from all the documentation on Apache2 and Passenger whether I should just:

gem install Passenger

and then

passenger-install-apache2-module

Would that give both Apache and Passenger or do I have to 'apt-get apache2' and then run the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a gem wouldn't install a system package such as Apache. You'll need to install Apache using your distro's package manager (apt-get in this instance) and then install Passenger and its modules.

Comment: Dan thanks very much for your prompt response.  I'll now go and try this out.